# Front end development: where to start?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, frontend

I'm very sorry if that question has been asked already, couldn't find anything closely related though.

By now I've pretty much learned HTML/HTML5, CSS/3, learned using JQuery (not saying there's nowhere to improve, obviously there is). I really want to start learning front-end dev (client MVC, etc). I've started learning backbone.js, but it turns out i'm having difficulties learning it. Am I missing something? I've read "JS: Good Parts" and Javascript Garden is basically my go-to source yet I still get confused.

I'd appreciate any recommendations as to what I should learn/practice first, thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My favorite answer for that is always - *start your own side-project*.

Pickup any simple existing application, ToDo list, issue tracker, blog platform, what ever and  spend energy to make it done. Host sources on github, search for similar applications to inspire.

You would not believe how many *actual* questions you would have, by just trying the things out. If you already have good skills with HTML/CSS and JS you'll be able to build something really valuable and learn a lot.

Backbone.js is good, but could be really difficult to start with. Do, some learning curve - implement same simple app in jQuery, then Backbone, then Angular.js. It will give you great client MVC overview.

Answer (score 2):

Two things

1. Don't quit.
2. Stackoverflow.

You can read all you want and it will definitely help, but in the end, you'll just have to start, work through it and finish something. Finishing is very important, so I would recommend starting simple, for example, build your own todo with an [example](http://backbonejs.org/docs/todos.html) on the side and work from there.

Comment: Not quitting, of course. I actually did a todo list, but i am still somewhat confused as to how it works and that pretty much makes it difficult for me to make something of my own. Guess I should just spend some more time learning it.

Comment: Did you build it, or did you copy it? Ok, by building I mean: build it! Not copy it. You have to understand what you are doing. That is why the todo example is great. It has a view, a model and a collection. Console.log is your friend. Log every method and it's variables and read 'm, understand 'm.

Answer (score 1):

Different people have different learning styles, so not all answers you will get will work for you (except GijsJanB's "Don't quit"). Personally, once I am through a tutorial or other documentation, I like to study a real-world system of substantial size. Two that I've looked at and might match your interests are:

- [Brackets](http://brackets.io/): a Javascript/HTML/CSS editor written entirely in Javascript. Written and maintained by Adobe, open source and available on Github via this link.
- [Travis-web](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-web): the front-end of the Travis-CI continuous integration framework, based on the Ember framework. Written largely in CoffeeScript, not JavaScript proper.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest AngularJS (http://angularjs.org/). Why? Because it has a pretty good tutorial section, good documentation AND it's backed by a large company (Google).

But unfortunately, the learning is still up to you ;-)

Answer (score 0):

A free online resource is w3schools, it teaches you back-end too(PhP and mySQL).I really suggest you to learn Angular2, this is a great js framework that most front-end developers use. Always practice,code at least 2 hours a day, make a lot of websites for your portofolio, learn how to make slideshows and animated text, you can even learn how to make a working login page, and a working contact form(a lot of cients want theese stuff). Learn photoshop and illustrator because clients want great design these days.One thing you have to remember is that you never stop learning,if you ever think that you finished learning it emans that you are at the beginning.Good luck and never forget the semicolons :)